# Legacy tests fails with EndpointNotFoundException because WcfTestClient does not start

Tags: c#, mstest, service-reference, wcftestclient

The legacy code uses a service reference called DesignTime2ServiceReference and it connects to endpoint http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/XXX

I have added "*/client:WcfTestClient.exe*" into **[project > Properties > Debug > Start Options > Command Line Arguments]**. When I do that the tests passes *if they are debugged*. But if I simply run them, they still fail.

Of cause I've tried to use the same trick for **[project > Properties > Release > ...]** but that does not work.

I am currently using VS 2022.

I have no idea how that was supposed to work once - and more pressingly - how to make it work now.

The tests are integration tests, implemented in MS Test and calling this code direcly:

```
using (var client = new DesignTime2ServiceReference.XXXClient())
```

Comment: I should add that the service reference Address is: 
http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/XXX/mex

Comment: Ok, so if I locate my svc-file and click F5, I can get the WcfTestClient up and running. And then I can run the tests.
Would be nice if there was a way to make this happen in the tests themselves, though.